# How can I use a function jQuery to build an object set, and return this new object?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to return an object of elements starting from an arbitrary mid point in sequence back around to before the midpoint. Basic HTML would look like this.

```
<div id-"units">
    <div id="unit1"></div>
    <div id="unit2"></div>
    <div id="unit3"></div>
    <div id="unit4"></div>
</div>

<button id="but1">Button 1</button>
<button id="but2">Button 2</button>
<button id="but3">Button 3</button>
<button id="but4">Button 4</button>
```

I figured I could create the object based around the selected item and use a function to include the remaining elements (in sequence).

```
$('#but1, #but2, #but3, #but4').click(function(){
    function addMore(limit, count, start){
        if(start == count){
            return output;
        }else if(count > limit){
            addMore(limit, 0, start);
        }else{
            output.add($('#subban'+count));
            console.log($('#subban'+count));
            count++;
            addMore(limit, count, start);
        }
    }
    var clicked = $(this).attr('id').replace('but',''),
    limit = $('#units div').length - 1;
    output = $('#unit'+clicked),
    count = clicked + 1;
    addMore(limit, count, clicked);
});
```

I am not getting the results I would expect with console.log and seem to be unable to return the complete output. Can anyone advise?

Comment: Why are you using `output.add()`? Did you mean to use `.append()`?

Comment: @Ian Thanks, I will go read up on `add()` again. I had mistakenly assumed this would work here. I will also try `append()`